# How do I make a file/mesh in Blender to export it as .fbx and import it in UnrealEngine4, to Subtract UE4's geometry from it?

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4, fbx

I have exported a .fbx mesh from Blender to UE4 and I need to subtract a part of it in UE4, but the subtraction with geometry doesn't seem to work. What do I change in the original .blend file to make it compatible with the UE4 geometry subtraction?

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK static geometry can't be used to substraction of bsp:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/62484/view.html

> Sean L ♦♦ STAFF Jul 19 '16 at 9:27 PM
>
> Keep in mind that this will only work with BSPs, which are placed in the Geometry section of the Modes tab. If you are using a static mesh, this will not work.

and you can't export/convert static geometry to bsp:
https://www.epicgames.com/unrealtournament/forums/unreal-tournament-development/ut-development-level-design/13535-converting-static-meshes-to-bsp